# Spark Dataframe is saved to MongoDB in wrong format

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using [Spark-MongoDB](https://github.com/Stratio/Spark-MongoDB)
and I am trying to save a DataFrame into MongoDB :

```
val event = """{"Dev":[{"a":3},{"b":3}],"hr":[{"a":6}]}"""
val events = sc.parallelize(event :: Nil)
val df = sqlc.read.json(events)
val saveConfig = MongodbConfigBuilder(Map(Host -> List("localhost:27017"),
 Database -> "test", Collection -> "test", SamplingRatio -> 1.0, WriteConcern -> "normal",
 SplitSize -> 8, SplitKey -> "_id"))
df.saveToMongodb(saveConfig.build)
```

I'm expecting the data to be saved as the input string, but what is actually saved is:

> { "_id" : ObjectId("57cedf4bd244c56e8e783a45"), "Dev" : [ { "a" : NumberLong(3), "b" : null }, { "a" : null, "b" : NumberLong(3) } ], "hr" : [ { "a" : NumberLong(6) } ] }

I want to avoid those null values and duplicates, Any idea?

Comment: There are no duplicates here and explicit `NULL` is expected.  These exactly a format you get from parsed JSON when mapped to Spark schema.

Comment: So is there a way to map it back to the original format (without null) before saving?

Comment: Its because you are importing the json data into a DataFrame and that sets the schema for all the data.  If the connector supports it the use the `SparkContext` instead and save the RDD. Failing that the https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/ does support it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried event defined as below using backslash:

```
val event = "{\"Dev\":[{\"a\":3},{\"b\":3}],\"hr\":[{\"a\":6}]}"
```