# Spark: import data frame to mongodb (scala)

Tags: mongodb, scala

Given the following data frame in spark:

```
Name,LicenseID_1,TypeCode_1,State_1,LicenseID_2,TypeCode_2,State_2,LicenseID_3,TypeCode_3,State_3    
"John","123ABC",1,"WA","456DEF",2,"FL","789GHI",3,"CA"
"Jane","ABC123",5,"AZ","DEF456",7,"CO","GHI789",8,"GA"
```

How could I use scala in spark to write this into mongodb as collection of document as follows:

```
{ "Name" : "John", 
  "Licenses" : 
  {
    [
      {"LicenseID":"123ABC","TypeCode":"1","State":"WA" },
      {"LicenseID":"456DEF","TypeCode":"2","State":"FL" },
      {"LicenseID":"789GHI","TypeCode":"3","State":"CA" }
    ]
  }
},

{ "Name" : "Jane", 
  "Licenses" : 
  {
    [
      {"LicenseID":"ABC123","TypeCode":"5","State":"AZ" },
      {"LicenseID":"DEF456","TypeCode":"7","State":"CO" },
      {"LicenseID":"GHI789","TypeCode":"8","State":"GA" }
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried to do this but got block at the following code:

```
 val customSchema = StructType(Array( StructField("Name", StringType, true), StructField("LicenseID_1", StringType, true), StructField("TypeCode_1", StringType, true), StructField("State_1", StringType, true), StructField("LicenseID_2", StringType, true), StructField("TypeCode_2", StringType, true), StructField("State_2", StringType, true), StructField("LicenseID_3", StringType, true), StructField("TypeCode_3", StringType, true), StructField("State_3", StringType, true)))
 val license = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").schema(customSchema).load("D:\\test\\test.csv")
 case class License(LicenseID:String, TypeCode:String, State:String)
 case class Data(Name:String, Licenses: Array[License])
 val transformedData = license.map(data => Data(data(0),Array(License(data(1),data(2),data(3)),License(data(4),data(5),data(6)),License(data(7),data(8),data(9)))))

<console>:46: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Any
 required: String
       val transformedData = license.map(data => Data(data(0),Array(License(data(1),data(2),data(3)),License(data(4),data(5),data(6)),License(data(7),data(8),data(9)))))
...
```

Comment: please be more specific about exactly what problem you are having. Maybe post some of the code you've already tried.

Comment: As you can see, given the multi-column with similar info (three separate license info spanning multiple columns), I want to import that into mongodb as a document with the "Licenses" as an attribute name and the value as an array of licenses of name value pairs containing each license info.

Comment: Have you tried to write any code to do that? If so, post it and indicate where the problem is. If not, make an attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your question , adding example how to save data spark and Mango

- https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/current/
- https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/current/scala-api/

  import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
  import com.mongodb.spark.sql._

  val sc: SparkContext // An existing SparkContext.
  val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()

  //mongo spark helper
  val df = MongoSpark.load(sparkSession)  // Uses the SparkConf

**Read**

```
sparkSession.loadFromMongoDB() // Uses the SparkConf for configuration
sparkSession.loadFromMongoDB(ReadConfig(Map("uri" -> "mongodb://example.com/database.collection"))) // Uses the ReadConfig

sparkSession.read.mongo()
sparkSession.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql").load()

// Set custom options:
sparkSession.read.mongo(customReadConfig)
sparkSession.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql").options.
 (customReadConfig.asOptions).load()
```

The connector provides the ability to persist data into MongoDB.

```
    MongoSpark.save(centenarians.write.option("collection", "hundredClub"))
    MongoSpark.load[Character](sparkSession, ReadConfig(Map("collection" ->
```

"data"), Some(ReadConfig(sparkSession)))).show()

Alternative to save data

```
dataFrameWriter.write.mongo()
dataFrameWriter.write.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql").save()
```

Comment: Reading and writing to mongo is not my problem. The problem is how to restructure the data (eg. from columns for similar data to array of key value pair) and then save it into mongodb so that it appears as in the sample json.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39389700/spark-dataframe-is-saved-to-mongodb-in-wrong-format

Answer (score 0):

Adding .toString fixed the issue and I was able to saved to mongodb the format I wanted.

```
val transformedData = license.map(data => Data(data(0).toString,Array(License(data(1).toString,data(2).toString,data(3).toString),License(data(4).toString,data(5).toString,data(6).toString),License(data(7).toString,data(8).toString,data(9).toString))))
```